# Question related to the trace and the commutator of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $K$ be any field and $n\in \mathbb N$. For every $A\in M_n(K)$, define a linear form $\lambda_A: M_n(K) \rightarrow K$ by sending the matrix $M$ to $\lambda_A(M):= \operatorname{Tr}(AM)$. The map $\lambda: M_n(K) \rightarrow M_n(K)^*$ defined this way is an isomorphism, as can be seen from injectivity and equality of dimensions (which are finite). The question is the following.

> Let $A, B\in M_n(K)$ be two matrices such that for every $M\in M_n(K)$ that commutes with $A$ (that is, such that $AM=MA$), we have $\lambda_B(M)=0$. Prove that $B=AC-CA$ for some matrix $C\in M_n(K)$.

The reciprocal being clearly true, the statement above in fact exactly characterizes all the matrices that can be written as $AC-CA$ for some matrix $C\in M_n(K)$.

As a preliminary question, I managed to show that 
$$\operatorname{Ker}(\operatorname{Tr})=\operatorname{Span}\{AB-BA\,|\,A,B\in M_n(K)\}$$
The inclusion of the right-hand space - which I call $E$ - inside the kernel is indeed clear. However, it may not be clear that the right-hand space is a hyperplane. If we assumed it were not, we may find another hyperplane $H$ such that $E\subset H$, and $H\not = \operatorname{Ker}(\operatorname{Tr})$. The hyperplane $H$ is the kernel of some linear form which is linearly independant on $\operatorname{Tr}$. It can be uniquely written as $\lambda_X$ for some matrix $X\in M_n(K)$ which is not a multiple of the identity matrix $I_n$. However, the condition that $\lambda_X$ vanishes on $E$ implies that $X$ is a multiple of the identity, so we get a contradiction. Hence, $E$ is a hyperplane and so by equality of dimensions, we must have the equality above (note that the kernel of $\operatorname{Tr}$ is never trivial).

I have been trying to solve the problem using this result, however I can't progress further. Taking $M=I_n$, we may express $B$ as $XY-YX$ for some matrices $X,Y \in M_n(K)$. Considering $A$, we may also express $BA$ as a commutator. But the problem is that we have no idea what these commutators would look like. In particular, I can't think of any way to prove that one of the matrices could be $A$.

Could you please give me any hint/advices that could lead me to the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider the operator $ad_A : M_n(K) \to M_n(K)$ defined by:
$$ad_A(M)=AM-MA$$
then $A$ and $M$ commute iff $ad_A(M)=0$ and the problem you are trying to solve can be rewritten as:

> Show that $\lambda_B(M)=0$, $ \forall M \in \ker(ad_A)$ if and only if $B \in \operatorname{im}(ad_A)$.

---

Remarks:

- using the inclusion and the properties of $\lambda$ you have already proven and denoting $d=\dim(\ker(ad_A))$ you can show that both are subspace of dimension $\dim(\operatorname{im}(ad_A))=n^2-d$.
- an even more direct way is the following: noticing that $(A,B) \mapsto \operatorname{Tr}(B^T A)=\lambda_{B^T}(A)$ is a scalar product you need to prove:
  $$B^T \in \ker(ad_A)^\perp \Leftrightarrow B \in \operatorname{im}(ad_A)$$
  which can remind you of some classical results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your illuminating answer. The way you made me look at the problem allowed me to successfully conclude the exercise. :-)